# how to change ids of datepicker control dynamically and make it work?

Tags: jquery, dom, datepicker

I have 4 columns. All these columns have datepickers in top. 
I want to allow users to remove the column they wish and add a column again at will. 
for that, I just want the columns to be ordered.

So if the columns are ordered like : 1 2 3 4, and say, user deletes 2, 
I want to rename the remaining columns as 1 2 3.

But after I do that, if I select a date in column 2, column 3's dates are also being changed.

So, currently I am destroying the datepickers and resetting them in a loop. Its taking insane amount of time to do so.

How do we solve this ?

Comment: If you give a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish with the switching we could probably find a good solution.

Comment: original question edited with real situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to swap them?

I think after attaching the date pickers, they don't care what `id` was originally used to select them, as the events, etc are attached to the DOM elements themselves.

I don't think you *can* swap them without unbinding them and rebinding all the events. If it is the positions you'd like to swap, I think that could be achieved through jQuery with help from CSS.

Comment: I have 4 columns. I want to allow users to remove the column they wish and add a column again at will. for that, I just want the columns to be ordered. So if the columns are ordered like : 1 2 3 4, and say, user deletes 2, I want to rename the remaining columns as 1 2 3. But after I do that, if I select a date in column 2, column 3's dates are also being changed. How do we solve this ?

Comment: @Shrinath I think you could solve all of this by programming the datepicker relative to its column, and not defining an explicit indexes.

Comment: it seems a good plan, but dont we need ids ?? I named the ids as column1 column2 and so on.. and I am sorting them based on it..

Comment: how do you propose I do it ? I am not getting it :(

Comment: @Shrinath Why must they have `id` s?